# How do I install aiogram on raspberry pi with python version 3.11 (python pre-assembled and installed)?

Tags: python

How do I install aiogram on raspberry pi with python version 3.11 (python pre-assembled and installed)?
On the standard version 3.7.3 everything is error-free.
When trying to set airogram
python3 --version
Python 3.11.0a6+
pip --version
pip 22.0.4 from /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
The platform is raspberry pi

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/network_folder/bot_2021_2semestr $ pip3.11 install aiog                                     ram
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting aiogram
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/aiogram/aiogram-2.19-py3-none-any                                     .whl (187 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<3.9.0,>=3.8.0
  Using cached aiohttp-3.8.1.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting Babel<2.10.0,>=2.9.1
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/babel/Babel-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-an                                     y.whl (8.8 MB)
Collecting certifi>=2021.10.8
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/certifi/certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3                                     -none-any.whl (151 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-6.0.2-cp311-cp311-linux_armv7l.whl
Collecting charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/charset-normalizer/charset_normal                                     izer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
Collecting async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/async-timeout/async_timeout-4.0.2                                     -py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1
  Using cached frozenlist-1.3.0.tar.gz (65 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/aiosignal/aiosignal-1.2.0-py3-non                                     e-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/attrs/attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-a                                     ny.whl (60 kB)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.7.2.tar.gz (168 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pytz>=2015.7
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/pytz/pytz-2021.3-py3-none-any.whl                                      (511 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/idna/idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (6                                     4 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp, frozenlist, yarl
  Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [107 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/typedefs.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_server.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/helpers.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/locks.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/log.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohtt                                     p
      copying aiohttp/web_runner.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/tcp_helpers.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/worker.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_routedef.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_ws.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_websocket.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_fileresponse.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/multipart.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/formdata.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_writer.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/resolver.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_reqrep.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/payload_streamer.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_protocol.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_middlewares.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_request.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_log.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_ws.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_parser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_app.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/connector.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/payload.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_response.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/tracing.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/base_protocol.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohtt                                     p
      copying aiohttp/client_proto.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/hdrs.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/streams.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/test_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/cookiejar.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/pytest_plugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/abc.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      running egg_info
      writing aiohttp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to aiohttp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to aiohttp.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to aiohttp.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in d                                     istribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in d                                     istribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in di                                     stribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in d                                     istribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in d                                     istribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in dis                                     tribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in d                                     istribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp/*.html'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying aiohttp/_cparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_find_header.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_find_header.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_find_header.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_headers.pxi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_helpers.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_helpers.pyi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_helpers.pyx -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_parser.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_parser.pyx -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_writer.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_writer.pyx -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_websocket.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_websocket.pyx -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_cparser.pxd.hash -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aio                                     http/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_find_header.pxd.hash -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11                                     /aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_helpers.pyi.hash -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aio                                     http/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_helpers.pyx.hash -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aio                                     http/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_http_parser.pyx.hash -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11                                     /aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_http_writer.pyx.hash -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11                                     /aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_websocket.pyx.hash -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/a                                     iohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/hdrs.py.hash -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp/                                     .hash
      running build_ext
      building 'aiohttp._websocket' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.11
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.11/aiohttp
      gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/pi                                     /.local/include/python3.11 -c aiohttp/_websocket.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.                                     11/aiohttp/_websocket.o
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:198:12: fatal error: longintrepr.h: Немає такого файл                                     а або каталогу
         #include "longintrepr.h"
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit                                     h pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
  Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      **********************
      * Accellerated build *
      **********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/frozenlist
      copying frozenlist/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/frozenlist
      running egg_info
      writing frozenlist.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to frozenlist.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to frozenlist.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'frozenlist.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in d                                     istribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in d                                     istribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in di                                     stribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in d                                     istribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in d                                     istribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in dis                                     tribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in d                                     istribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'frozenlist/*.html'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'frozenlist.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying frozenlist/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/frozenlist
      copying frozenlist/_frozenlist.pyx -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/frozenli                                     st
      copying frozenlist/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/frozenlist
      running build_ext
      building 'frozenlist._frozenlist' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.11
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.11/frozenlist
      gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/pi                                     /.local/include/python3.11 -c frozenlist/_frozenlist.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7                                     l-3.11/frozenlist/_frozenlist.o
      frozenlist/_frozenlist.c: In function ‘__Pyx_AddTraceback’:
      frozenlist/_frozenlist.c:432:62: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplet                                     e type ‘PyFrameObject’ {aka ‘struct _frame’}
         #define __Pyx_PyFrame_SetLineNumber(frame, lineno)  (frame)->f_lineno =                                      (lineno)
                                                                    ^~
      frozenlist/_frozenlist.c:7127:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_PyFram                                     e_SetLineNumber’
           __Pyx_PyFrame_SetLineNumber(py_frame, py_line);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit                                     h pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for frozenlist
  Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      **********************
      * Accelerated build *
      **********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_url.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_quoting.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_quoting_py.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/yarl
      running egg_info
      writing yarl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to yarl.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in d                                     istribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in                                      distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying yarl/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_quoting_c.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_quoting_c.pyi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/_quoting_c.pyx -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/yarl
      copying yarl/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.11/yarl
      running build_ext
      building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.11
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.11/yarl
      gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/pi                                     /.local/include/python3.11 -c yarl/_quoting_c.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.11/                                     yarl/_quoting_c.o
      yarl/_quoting_c.c:198:12: fatal error: longintrepr.h: Немає такого файла а                                     бо каталогу
         #include "longintrepr.h"
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit                                     h pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build aiohttp frozenlist yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, frozenlist, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```